# issue with looping my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

i'm very new to programming, i have been interested in it for a while.  I'm currently studying learn python the hard way by zed a. shaw.  I've come to exercise 31 and i'm trying to develop my skills by developing a little game my children could play.  I am trying insert loops into my code so that if you get game over it takes you back to the top.  I am now having trouble with line 4 of my code.

```
randomnum = random.randint(0,20)
```

i'm getting error

> NameError: name 'random' is not defined.

when i add def before the line it still isn't running it.

here is my updated code:

```
print("""Welcome to my game! \nsee if you can complete the task ahead""")
print("You enter a dark cave with a corridor, do you go stealth or charge in?")

randomnum = random.randint(0,20)
stealth = input ("> ")
charge = input ("> ")

if stealth:
    print("you see an enemy outpost on your left.")
    print("what do you do?")
    print("1. continue to sneak past?")
    print("2. attack the outpost?")

    outpost = input("> ")

    if outpost == "1":
        print(randomnum)
        if randomnum < 11:
            print("you're seen and die!")
            print("game over!")
        else:
            print("success! continue to next zone.")

    else:
        print(randomnum)
        if randomnum < 11:
            print("you fail and die")
            print("game over!")
        else:
            print("success! you defeat the goblins.\ncontinue to next zone.")

if charge:
    print("you see an enemy outpost in front of you.")
    print("what do you do?")
    print("1. charge with a battle cry?")
    print("2. attack from distance?")

    outpost = input("> ")

    if outpost == "1":
        print(randomnum)
        if randomnum < 11:
            print("you fail your attack and die!")
            print("game over!")
        else:
            print("success! you defeat the goblins.\nContinue to next zone.")

    else:
        print(randomnum)
        if randomnum < 8:
            print("you fail and die")
            print("game over!")
        else:
            print("success! you defeat the goblins. \ncontinue to next zone.")
```

Comment: This `print(random.randint(1,20))`   just prints a number . Store it in a variable and use that in your comparison - your  `if`s do not make any sense. `if ("< 11"):`  is always true, the () are not needed - and any non-emptry string is always `True` ..

Comment: `if ("< 11"):` what? I think you have a misunderstanding of data types. Please read on the difference between `str`, `int`, etc. Also how to properly assign to and use variables

Comment: as i said i'm only just learning the language, any help is very welcome.

Comment: You need not import `random` multiple times in the script. Importing once(at the top of the script, by custom) in this script will allow you to use it multiple times thereafter, proveded you don't asssign some other value to the name `random` (e.g `random = 2`). An explanation of the mechanics of this game would be helpful, I can't get what you're trying to achive with the if statements.

Comment: in exercise 31 of LPTHW there is a code that you type out, at the end of the exercise zed asks you to create a game using the code he has just had you write out to test your understanding... my game has gotten a little too complicated for my knowledge, but its all a learning curve

Comment: Good luck on your Python journey! :)

Comment: really helpful cheers

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if the randomly generated number is less that 11 or greater than 10 you would use:

```
    randomnum = random.randint(0,20)
    print(randomnum)
    if randomnum < 11:
        print("you fail and die")
        print("game over!")
        start()
elif randomnum > 10:
    print("success! you defeat the goblins. \ncontinue to next zone.")`
```

However, as the number can only either be < 11 or > 10, you can use the else statement:

```
randomnum = random.randint(0,20)
print(randomnum)
if randomnum < 11:
    print("you fail and die")
    print("game over!")
    start()
else:
    print("success! you defeat the goblins. \ncontinue to next zone.")`
```

Comment: thanks for the help folks.  do i have the correct system to loop back to the beginning if the user fails?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not input random.

Go to your code and make a new line below the first line and type 'import random'

It should work!